# Python Error: “ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack” in socket programming

Tags: python

In Python, when I run this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket
s=socket.socket()

s.connect(('www.sina.com.cn',80))
s.send(b'GET /HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.sina.com.cn\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')

buffer=[]
while True:
    d=s.recv(1024)
    if d:
        buffer.append(d)
    else:
        break
data=b''.join(buffer)
s.close()

header,html = data.split(b'\r\n\r\n',1)
print(header.decode('utf-8'))

with open('sina_test.html','wb') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

I get this error:

> line 19, in  (header,html,h) = data.split(b'\r\n\r\n',1)
>   ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

What does that error mean?

Comment: It means that `split` in this case only returns one value or an array with only one value. So you can not assign it to two variables.

Comment: So it meas that maybe the split can only return one value but I use two value to accept it,isn't it?

Comment: The answer of @mic4ael might help you, just change the last parameter to 2

Comment: I try,but this error  still appear.@fafl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `split` method limits how many items the method will return

```
header,html = data.split(b'\r\n\r\n',1)
```

Here you are trying to unpack more than 1 even though you specified that `split` should only return 1 item

Comment: Thanks,that is what I ignore.

Answer (score 1):

There's a SPACE before the HTTP

```
# wrong
s.send(b'GET /HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.sina.com.cn\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')
# correct
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.sina.com.cn\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n')
```

The wrong usage maybe send you this information:

```
print(data) 
<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>Not Found on Accelerator</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n\n<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black">\n<H1>Not Found on Accelerator</H1>\n<HR>\n\n<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>\nDescription: Your request on the specified host was not found.\nCheck the location and try again.\n</B></FONT>\n<HR>\n</BODY>\n
```

The right information is just like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 03:28:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 605221
Connection: close
Last-Modified: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 03:27:02 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Tue, 23 Jan 2018 03:29:37 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60
X-Powered-By: shci_v1.03
Age: 1
Via: http/1.1 ctc.jiangsu.ha2ts4.82 (ApacheTrafficServer/6.2.1 [cHs f ])
X-Cache: HIT.82
X-Via-CDN: f=edge,s=ctc.jiangsu.ha2ts4.83.nb.sinaedge.com,c=58.213.91.6;f=Edge,s=ctc.jiangsu.ha2ts4.82,c=61.155.142.83
X-Via-Edge: 1516678118627065bd53afa8e9b3d553f23b9
```

That's why ValueError occurs.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your string (`data`) does not contain the regex you are trying to split accordingly and therefore - `data.split(b'\r\n\r\n',1) == data` which cannot be assigned to header and html.